# Adding to dictionary error: function results in 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def addKey(d, L1 = None, L2 = None, L3 = None, L4 = None):
  if L4 != None:
    d[L1][L2][L3] = L4
  elif L3 != None:
    d[L1][L2] = L3
  elif L2 != None:
    d[L1] = L2
  else:
    d[L1] = ""

dermDict = {}
addKey(dermDict, "Skin Finding")
addKey(dermDict, "Skin Finding", "Neonatal acne")
addKey(dermDict, "Skin Finding", "Neonatal acne", "Nickname")

print(dermDict)
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

However, when I comment out the last line (with "Nickname" in it), it works.

Why is this?? How come my function works for the others, but not this one?

Comment: `d[L1] = ""` makes `d[L1]` a string, and so does `d[L1] = L2`. A later attempt to index it (`d[L1][L2]`) naturally fails. What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output would be {'Skin Finding': {'Neonatal acne': {'Nickname':}}

Comment: And now that I've thought it through, I've edited my code and it works!! Your comment helped a lot!